# Android Cursor wont Loop, Application Freezes

Tags: android

So here it goes, i have this application retrieves records from database, i have 5 entries from my database, and retrieved its using this code;

```
Cursor c = dbconnection.rawQuery("SELECT * from Patients", null);
```

after that i looped it to retrieve the data pero row in my Database as such;

```
c.moveToFirst();
while(!c.isAfterLast())
{
 //Some code to put records per column in to a Patient Object 
 c.moveToNext();
}
```

So my problem is that as it enters the loop my Emulator freezes and as i tried to display per record into a Log, i won't cuz the emulator it self already frozed.

Can somebody enlighten me into this matter, This issue is really really new to me

### EDIT

yes already tried what baya and ofir suggested.. they worked out but i have this null error during iteration with this loop code

```
Cursor c = dbHelper.retrieveAllData();

                c.moveToFirst();

                while(c.moveToNext())
                {
                    Log.d("dbcheck",Integer.toString(c.getPosition()));
                    //Log.d("dbcheck",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstname")));
                    //Log.d("dbcheck",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastname")));
                    **p.setFname(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstname")));**
                    p.setMi(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("middleinitial")));
                    p.setLname(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastname")));
                    p.setAddr(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")));
                    p.setAge(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("age")));
                    p.setMed_history(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("med_history")));
                    p.setPat_status(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("status")));
                    patientList.add(p);

                }
```

i have a null exception error on the p.setFname() line.. i don't know how it became null where in fact i already displayed it with Log using that code that is commented out..

Comment: have u initialized the object p.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try,

```
         Cursor c = dbconnection.rawQuery("SELECT * from Patients", null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {

        Patient p;

        while(c.moveToNext) {

            //initialize ur object to store new patient info.
            p = new Patient();
            p.setFname(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstname")));

            //add newly created patient to ur list
            patientList.add(p);

        }
    }
c.close();
```

Comment: yes yes it worked out... but i have a null exception as explained above, i've edited it

Answer (score 0):

Try do it like this:

```
    // return all columns
    Cursor cursor = mDb.query(Patients, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if ((cursor != null) && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
       while(cursor.moveToNext()){

    //Some code to put records per column in to a Patient Object 

    }
                    cursor.close();
   }
```

Comment: yes yes it worked out... but i have a null exception as explained above, i've edited it

Comment: @lemoncodes Check your DB, if you say that you already print it, I can't think way it's not working. Are you sure that when you use log command it's printing the right data?

Comment: I don't think you need the next line 'c.moveToFirst();', I don't use it in my project and it's work just fine.

Comment: it already worked.. tnx guys.. i found the null error part.. the object wasn't properly initialize hehe sorry about that.. my bad... but tnx anyways for the inputs!